# how to link a database value as the key to a multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have an array that displays some values from the database in the form below

```
[Worst] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1234567
        [1] => 189818006457
        )

[Best] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1006999
        [1] => 9
        )
```

but i want a situation where another column name in the database will be used as the array key instead of the numerical figure 0 and 1. I want the output to look like the one below.

```
[Worst] => Array
    (
        [john] => 1234567
        [rock] => 189818006457
        )

[Best] => Array
    (
        [smith] => 1006999
        [joy] => 9
        )
```

where john is on the same row in the database with number 1234567, rock also on the same row with number 189818006457, smith on the same row with number 1006999 and joy on the same row with number 9 in the database. How do i go about it. Thanks.
The excerpted code that produced the result above is below

```
 $array2 = array();

 foreach($statement->get_result() as $row){
     array_push($array2, $row['imei_number'] ,$row['speed']);
     }

     $input = $array2;  
     $groups =    //array in form of the following
 [Worst] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 13
            )

    [Best] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            )

// First create an associative array that maps a given value to a group number
     $map = array();
    foreach ($groups as $group => $subarray) {
        $map = $map + array_combine($subarray, array_fill(0, count($subarray), $group));
    }

    // This iterate pairs of the input data
    foreach (array_chunk($input, 2) as list($v, $k)) {
        $result[$map[$k]][] = $v ;
    }
```

Comment: how do you populate that array? show your code!

Comment: but it's something like `$array[$row['name']] = $row['id'];`

Comment: [here is the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)

Comment: it was an algorithm that i used to compute those results.

Comment: Show your coding attempt to self-solve.  We are not meant to manufacture new code, we are meant to repair your code.  Show enough code **as an edit on the question** for us to reproduce the issue.  Include information about all variables used.

Comment: yes. You are right. this is the code   foreach (array_chunk($input, 2) as list($v, $k)) {
  $result[$map[$k]][] = $v ;
 } @jeff

Comment: am very confused about the what to do next. It is as if i don't know the code to write to solve this. Pardon please am a newbie in php @mickmackusa

Comment: Post your database structure and a sample of the data in there.  Then post the expected array you want to build from that.  I can't make heads or tails of your question with what is in there right now.